# How to prove that $P \rightarrow Q$ is equivalent with $\neg P \lor Q $?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

In my book about Logic, which is called 'Language, Proof and Logic', by the way, there is explained that the conditional $ P \rightarrow Q $ is equivalent with $\neg P \lor Q$.

[There is another answer on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/920766/equivalence-of-p-rightarrow-q-and-lnot-p-lor-q) that gives as answer: 'just compare the truth tables and you can see that they are equivalent'. However, I would like to know how to prove this using formal propositional logic. This should be possible, right?

Comment: How do you define $P \to Q$?

Comment: Which kind of formal proof system for propositional logic do you want to prove the equivalence in? There are several quite different ones.

Comment: This is often given as the definition, although I prefer $P\implies Q\equiv \neg[P \land \neg Q]$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalence of $a \rightarrow b$ and $\lnot a \vee b$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243949/equivalence-of-a-rightarrow-b-and-lnot-a-vee-b)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Layout:**

To prove that $\neg P\lor Q$ is a formal consequence of $P\to Q$, start by assuming $P\to Q$ and further suppose that $\neg (\neg P\lor Q)$ holds. At this point you should prove $P\lor \neg P$ and perform $\lor$-$\text{Elim}$ on this disjunction. It's easy to find contradictions on both cases yielding $\neg \neg (\neg P\lor Q)$.

For the other direction, naturally start by assuming that $\neg P\lor Q$ holds and then assume $P$. Now start yet another subproof (within the assumption that $P$ holds) assuming that $\neg Q$ holds. At this point perform $\lor$-$\text{Elim}$ on the assumption $\neg P\lor Q$. It's easy to find a contradiction in this last subproof.

Answer (score 3):

1. $P → Q$ *(given)*
2. $Q \lor \neg Q$ *(tautology)*
3. $\neg Q → \neg P$ *(contrapositive of (1) )*
4. *from (2) and (3)*: $Q \lor \neg P$ *(modus ponens)*

Answer (score 0):

You may translate the two expressions using sheffer's stroke, symbol : |

- X | Y means , by definition ~ ( X & Y)
- X --> Y means ~ ( X & ~ Y) and, hence : X | ~Y
- X v Y means ~ ( ~X & ~Y) , hence : ~X | ~Y

Now, let ~P play the role of X and Q play the role of Y.

- **~P v Q means (~ ~ P | ~Q), that is : ( P | ~Q)** , using double negation.

Let P play the role of X and Q play the role of Y.

- **( P --> Q) means ( P | ~Q).**

The sheffer's stroke translation shows that the two formulas mean exactly the same thing; hence they are equivalent.