# Prove using Natural Deduction in predicate logic $(\forall x\ P(x))\to Q ⊢ \exists x (P(x)\to Q)$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I couldn't find a proper answer. I am pretty sure the universal quantifier elimination rule can't be applied directly and I tried proving by contradiction, but couldn't complete it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Is this a typo? Should the second $\to$ be a $\land$? Implications are not usually quantified existentially like this.

Comment: this is the question my instructor gave me

Comment: How exactly is your rule for existential quantifier elimination defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The following is a proof using natural deduction and, per your request, without using DeMorgan's law, null quantification laws, or contrapositive law:**

$1$. $\forall x P(x) \rightarrow Q$ ---- premise

$2$. $\neg \forall x P(x) \vee Q$ ---- implication law $1$

$3$. $Q \vee \neg \forall x P(x) $ ---- commutative law $2$

$4$. $\neg \neg Q \vee \neg \forall x P(x) $ ---- double negation law $3$

$5$. $\neg Q \rightarrow \neg \forall x P(x) $ ---- implication law $4$

_____ $6$. $\neg Q$ ---- ACP

_____ $7$. $\neg \forall x P(x)$ ---- modus ponens $5,6$

__________ $8$. $\neg \exists x \neg P(x)$ ---- AIP

_________________ $9$. $\neg P(x)$ ---- AIP

_________________ $10$. $\exists x \neg P(x)$ ---- $\exists$ intro $9$

_________________ $11$. $\exists x \neg P(x) \wedge \neg \exists x \neg P(x)$ ---- conjunction intro $8,10$

__________ $12$. $\neg \neg P(x)$ ---- IP $9$-$11$

__________ $13$. $P(x)$ ---- double negation $12$

__________ $14$. $\forall x P(x)$ ---- $\forall$ intro $13$

__________ $15$. $\forall x P(x) \wedge \neg \forall x P(x)$ ---- conjunction intro $7,14$

_____ $16$. $\neg \neg \exists x \neg P(x)$ ---- IP $8$-$15$

_____ $17$. $\exists x \neg P(x)$ ---- double negation $16$

$18$. $\neg Q \rightarrow \exists x \neg P(x)$ ---- CP $6$-$17$

_____ $19$. $\neg Q$ ---- ACP

_____ $20$. $\exists x \neg P(x)$ ---- modus ponens $18,19$

_____ $21$. $\neg P(b)$ ---- $\exists$ elim $20$

$22$. $\neg Q \rightarrow \neg P(b)$ ---- CP $19$-$21$

$23$. $\neg \neg Q \vee \neg P(b)$  ---- implication law $22$

$24$. $Q \vee \neg P(b)$  ---- double negation law $23$

$25$. $\neg P(b) \vee Q$  ---- commutative law $24$

$26$. $P(b) \rightarrow Q$  ---- implication law $25$

$27$. $\exists x (P(x) \rightarrow Q)$ ---- $\exists$ intro $26$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: @varkey I realized the proof I offered before was incomplete. I went from $\exists x \neg P(x) \vee Q$ to $\exists x (P(x) \rightarrow Q)$ in a single step, which assumes that $Q$ is in the scope of the existential quantifier $\exists$. However, it is NOT in the scope of the $\exists$; only $\neg P(x)$ is in the scope of $\exists$. I modified the proof above so that it's $100$% correct now. The statement $\exists x \neg P(x)$ must appear on its own line so that the existential quantifier can be removed. Later, the quantifier is reintroduced when $P(x) \rightarrow Q$ is on its own line.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but my instructor told us that we can't use any derived rules for the exam. So, can we assume ∀xP(x) directly, so as I can prove the contraposition part directly in the answer?

Comment: many of the rules of inference are "derived rules," so it's unclear to me which rules you are allowed to use. Could you tell me what rules you are are allowed to use?

Comment: we aren't allowed to use both contraposition and de - morgan's laws

Comment: thank you, also can we assume ∀xP(x) directly, so that I can prove the contraposition part directly in the answer?

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy The logic is correct, but something to point out is ,there is no direct application of "implication law" or "commutative law" in natural deduction, even it's not hard to prove, and I think a mistake on line $7$ to $8$ is the $\forall$ Elim only work like this:
$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$
$$\fitch{~~1.~\forall x\neg P(x)}{~~2.~\neg P(a)\hspace{10ex}{\forall}~\textsf{Elim}~1}$$

If the negtaion is in front of $\forall x P(x)$ like $\neg\forall x P(x)$, it not going to work $\dots$

Comment: To see why, it's because $\neg \forall x P(x)\equiv \exists x \neg P(x)$,

but after line $8$ the conclusion you made is based on $\forall x \neg P(x)$, which we don't have $\dots$

Comment: And because of those reasons, i  will downvote this answer

Comment: @Manx the laws of implication and commutativity are among the rules of inference (specifically, they are logically equivalent statement forms) that may be used in natural deduction. There is no issue there. However, I was absolutely incorrect in my application of instantiation when the quantifier was preceded by a negation. Instantiation and generalization must be performed on the entire line of proof. Thanks for pointing that out. I revised my proof above.

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy It looks better now, I removed the donwvote, but I'm still not sure you can directly apply implication or commutativity in natural deduction

Comment: @Manx Thank you. For what reason are you unsure about implication and commutativity? I'm just curious because i see no problem with it, and I understand them to be basic rules of inference that carry over from propositional to first order logic

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy I wouldn't say they are 'basic', since they are provable from a set of rules that we considered as 'basic' 

$\{\to$ Elim,$\to$Intro,$\land$ Elim,$\land$Intro,$\lor$ Elim,$\lor$Intro$\dots$etc$\}$

Comment: for example : ["implication law"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1002829)

, and for "commutative law" I would write:
$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$
$$\fitch{~~1.~P\lor Q}{\fitch{~~2.~P}{~~3.~P\lor Q\hspace{10ex}{\lor}~\textsf{Intro}~2}\\~~4.~P\to(Q\lor P)\hspace{6.3ex}{\to}~\textsf{Intro}~2-3\\\fitch{~~5.~Q}{~~6.~Q\lor P\hspace{10ex}{\lor}~\textsf{Intro}~5}\\~~7.~Q\to(Q\lor P)\hspace{6ex}{\to}~\textsf{Intro}~5-6\\~~8.~Q\lor P\hspace{14ex}{\lor}~\textsf{Elim}~1,2-3,5-6}$$

Answer (score 3):

Following @Matthew Daly's hint,

here would be the general structure of the proof:

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$
$$\fitch{~~1.~(\forall xP(x))\to Q}
{\fitch{~~2.~\neg(\forall xP(x)\lor\neg\forall xP(x))}{
\fitch{~~3.~\forall xP(x)}{~~
4.~(\forall xP(x))\lor(\neg(\forall x P(x)))\hspace{10ex}{\lor}~\textsf{Intro}~3\\~~
5.~\bot\hspace{32.6ex}{\bot}~\textsf{Intro}~2,4}\\~~
6.~\neg(\forall xP(x))\hspace{27.2ex}{\neg}~\textsf{Intro}~3-5\\~~
7.~(\forall xP(x))\lor(\neg(\forall xP(x)))\hspace{13.5ex}{\lor}~\textsf{Intro}~6\\~~
8.~\bot\hspace{36.4ex}{\bot}~\textsf{Intro}~2,7}\\~~
9.~(\forall xP(x))\lor(\neg(\forall xP(x)))\hspace{17ex}{\neg}~\textsf{Intro}~2-8\\
\fitch{~~
10.~\forall xP(x)}{
\fitch{~~
11.~P(a)}{~~
12.~Q\hspace{31.5ex}{\to}~\textsf{Elim}~1,10}\\~~
13.~P(a)\to Q\hspace{26.5ex}{\to}~\textsf{Intro}~11-12\\~~
14.~\exists x(P(x)\to Q)\hspace{23.1ex}{\exists}~\textsf{Intro}~13
}\\\fitch{~~
15.~\neg(\forall xP(x))}{\fitch{~~
16.~\neg\exists x(P(x)\to Q)}{\fitch{~~
17.~\boxed{a}}{\fitch{~~
18.~\neg P(a)}{\fitch{~~
19.~P(a)}{~~
20.~\bot\hspace{21ex}{\bot}~\textsf{Intro}~18,19~\\~~
21.~Q\hspace{21ex}{\bot}~\textsf{Elim}~20~}\\~~
22.~P(a)\to Q\hspace{16ex}{\to}\textsf{Intro}~19-21~\\~~
23.~\exists x(P(x)\to Q)\hspace{12ex}{\exists}~\textsf{Intro}~22~\\~~
24.~\bot\hspace{25ex}{\bot}~\textsf{Intro}~16,23~}\\~~
25.~\neg\neg P(a)\hspace{22.5ex}{\neg}~\textsf{Intro}~18-24~\\~~
26.~P(a)\hspace{25.5ex}{\neg}~\textsf{Elim}~25~}\\~~
27.~\forall xP(x)\hspace{26.5ex}{\forall}~\textsf{Intro}~17-26~\\~~
28.~\bot\hspace{32ex}{\bot}~\textsf{Intro}~15,27~}\\~~
29.~\exists x(P(x)\to Q)\hspace{22.5ex}{\neg}~\textsf{Intro}~16-28~}\\~~
30.~\exists x(P(x)\to Q)\hspace{26ex}{\lor}~\textsf{Elim}~9,10-14,15-29}$$

**From line $1-9$ we proved:**

"either ∀x P(x) is true or it isn't."

**From line $10-14$ we proved:**

"If it is true, then $Q$ is true and your $P(x)→Q$ is true for any value of x."

**From line $15-29$ we proved:**

"If it is not true, then you can choose some x such that $¬P(x)$. Then $P(x)→Q$ is vacuously true for that value of $x$."

**And line $30$ we finishes the prove.**

Answer (score 2):

Hint: either $\forall x\  P(x)$ is true or it isn't.

- If it is true, then $Q$ is true and your $P(x)\to Q$ is true for any value of $x$.
- If it is not true, then you can choose some $x$ such that $\neg P(x)$.  Then $P(x)\to Q$ is vacuously true for that value of $x$.

Comment: how do you prove it using natural deduction in predicate logic?

Comment: Assume $\neg\exists x~(P(x)\to Q)$, then assume $\forall x~P(x)$.  Use the hints to derive contradictions so you may discharge these assumptions .

Comment: I am confused as to how to derive Q. Can you do implication elimination before eliminating the quantifiers?

Comment: can someone please do it?

Answer (score 2):

> I am pretty sure the universal quantifier elimination rule can't be applied directly

Correct: you cannot apply universal elimination on part of a larger statement.

> I tried proving by contradiction, but couldn't complete it.

Too bad ... it's typically a good strategy for whenever you have to prove an existential and you can;t have an existential already to work with. In fact, below is a completed proof by Contradiction in Fitch. It does not use any equivalence principles.

[image]

Comment: Nice proof by contradiction!

Comment: Just finished the proof $\dots$ I looked though the steps of the second sub-proof, seems like it's exactly line $2-13$ of your proof, and i'm not sure if there is any easier methods $\dots$ probably proof by contradiction is better than do a direct proof in this case.

Comment: @Manx Yeah, I didn't realize that that would happen, but I see no other way with your set-up. It *would* be a short derivation if from $\neg \forall x \ P(x)$ you can go straight to $\exists x \ \neg P(x)$, but in the absence of that as a rule, you would again need Proof by Contradiction. So yes, you might as well do Proof by Contradiction all the way. Thanks!

Comment: @Bram28 It is unsurprising really, when you consider that $\neg \forall x~P(x)\vdash \exists x~\neg P(x)$ is $$(\forall x~P(x))\to\bot\vdash \exists x~(P(x)\to\bot)$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Yes, nice way of looking at it, thanks!