# Need to prove $(p \land q) \land (\lnot p \lor r) \rightarrow (q \lor r)$ is a tautology.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I need to prove the following expression is a tautology using propositional logic laws.

My current working out is as follows [not sure if it is correct]:

$$(p \land q)\land ( \lnot p \lor r) \rightarrow (q \lor r)$$

Taking the LHS: $(p \land q) \land (\lnot p \lor r)$

$( (p \land q) \land \lnot p) \lor ( (p \land q) \land r)$ [Using distributive law]

$( (p \land \lnot p) \land q) \lor  ( (p \land q) \land r)$ [Using associative law]

$( F \land q) \lor  ( (p \land q) \land r)$ [Using complement law]

$F \lor  ( (p \land q) \land r)$ [Using identity law]

This is where I get stuck. Is this the correct working so far? What other laws am I missing to prove the expression is a tautology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that
$$F \lor  ( (p \land q) \land r)=p \land q \land r$$
Then recall that [How to prove that $P \rightarrow Q$ is equivalent with $\neg P \lor Q $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/935640/how-to-prove-that-p-rightarrow-q-is-equivalent-with-neg-p-lor-q)

Hence, from your work, 
$$(p \land q)\land ( \lnot p \lor r) \rightarrow (q \lor r)$$
is equivalent to
$$\lnot(p \land q \land r)\lor (q \lor r)$$
that is, by using  [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws),
$$(\lnot p \lor \lnot q \lor \lnot r) \lor (q \lor r)=\lnot p \lor (\lnot q \lor q) \lor (\lnot r\lor r)=T.$$

Comment: Thanks! I got it now.

Answer (score 4):

$p \land q \land (\lnot p \lor r)$ implies $q$  $\tiny\text{… by simplification}$

$q$ implies $q \lor r$  $\tiny\text{… by addition}$

The rest is obvious.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure I follow you.

Comment: It's a natural deduction style argument, rather than propositional calculus.

Comment: That propositional calculus fad is a clumsy way to prove many propositions.  Why is it the only thing taught?  Have they discarded teaching P., Q|- R. @GrahamKemp

Answer (score 0):

In fact, from $(p\land q)\land (\neg p\lor r)$ we can even prove $q\land r$. Note in particular $p\land(\neg p\lor r)\to r$.